# Parsing string to java.sql.date

Tags: java, parsing, date

i hope you can help me.
My input is 22-01-1993

my code is

```
public String CreateCalendar (String titel, String startDate, String endDate, String note, String location, String email) throws SQLException, ParseException
{
    String stringToBeReturned ="";
    testConnection();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:s zzz YYYY");

    java.util.Date utilStartDate = format.parse(startDate);
    java.util.Date utilEndDate = format.parse(startDate);
    java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());
    java.sql.Date sqlEndDate = new java.sql.Date(utilEndDate.getTime());


    String [] keys = {"title","start","end", "note", "location", "active", "email"};
    String [] values = {titel, format.parse(startDate).toString(), format.parse(endDate).toString(), note, location, "1", email};
    qb.insertInto("calendar", keys).values(values).Execute();

    return stringToBeReturned;
}
```

however i get the error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "22-01-1993"
what am i doing wrong

Comment: Can you add  the stack trace and what the input/output it is trying to parse is?

Comment: @ditleev You should either ask a new question or edit your old one, not post an answer.

Comment: @ditleev I edited my answer to account for the second bug. I hope I did right, if not, write a comment and I will fix it.

Comment: Hi @Emz i really appreciate your help. i now get the error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "22-01-1993" im not too good at this parsing thing :)

Comment: @ditleev Updated once again. The input you are given `22-01-1993` is not what is expected in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format.parse(startDate).toString()` and `format.parse(endDate)` will do the trick for you.

---

To add to your second question.

`22-01-1993` this is how you give your data.

`Fri Jan 22 00:00:00 CET 1993` this is how it expects it.

So let's change `("dd-MM-yyyy")` to actually match it.

`("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:s zzz YYYY");`

That should do the trick.

---

Apperently it is not the same in PHP as Java, I updated the `data (...)` to match that. Information taken from

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

---

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:s zzz YYYY");

String startDate = new Date().toString();
```

*Outputs*

```
Fri Dec 05 23:15:39 CET 2014
```

So that works.

The way I see it now you don't need the following lines

```
java.util.Date utilStartDate = format.parse(startDate);
java.util.Date utilEndDate = format.parse(startDate);
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());
java.sql.Date sqlEndDate = new java.sql.Date(utilEndDate.getTime());
```

A problem when you are having the the following input `22-01-1993` is that it doesn't match what you are expected to have. You could extract the month, day and year from it, then build a new string with the rest of the data. However, that feels redundant.

Answer (score 0):

got it working, like this

```
public String CreateCalendar (String titel, String startDate, String endDate, String note, String location, String email) throws SQLException, ParseException
{
    String stringToBeReturned ="";
    testConnection();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
    format.parse(startDate);
    format.parse(endDate);


    String [] keys = {"title", "start", "end", "note", "location", "active", "email"};
    String [] values = {titel, startDate, endDate, note, location, "1", email};
    qb.insertInto("calendar", keys).values(values).Execute();

    return stringToBeReturned;
}
```